# OpenSea IPFS Metadata

Tags: solidity, web3js, ipfs, opensea

I have been testing my erc-721 contract with a link to my ipfs hash `ipfs://QmeB87321i121xN88bXZzmjSUXqS46B8bU3H9ocyTb8tJf` as the base token URI. The contracts are deployed and the items have been minted by me, but OpenSea can't read that metadata uri as expected. The documentation on OpenSea suggests that it should be sufficient.

**My Contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./ERC721Tradable.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

contract Creature is ERC721Tradable {
    constructor(address _proxyRegistryAddress)
        public
        ERC721Tradable("StygianCoins", "STG", _proxyRegistryAddress)
    {}

    function baseTokenURI() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmeB87321i121xN88bXZzmjSUXqS46B8bU3H9ocyTb8tJf";
    }

    function contractURI() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "https://contract-abis.herokuapp.com/api/contract/stygian-coins";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of pointing to your folder that has your files in IPFS, you'll need to point to a metadata file.

A Metadata file is a `json` formatted file that has information about the tokenId. You'd place your image URI in the `image` section. Here is an example:

```js
{
    "name": "You NFT token name",
    "description": "Something Cool here",
    "image": "ipfs://QmTgqnhFBMkfT9s8PHKcdXBn1f5bG3Q5hmBaR4U6hoTvb1?filename=Chainlink_Elf.png",
    "attributes": []
}
```

So on IPFS you'd have 2 files:

- One with the image
- One with the metadata.json which contains the URI from the image

Then, in your contract, you'll have to call the `_setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);` function (imported by the openzepplin erc721 package)

```
_setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);
```

The `_tokenURI` should be your metadata URL/URI. And the tokenId is the id of your NFT.

[Here is an example TokenURI in IPFS](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmT3nSKpJrEUWgeqGNiQPNEWcP2cousZNfQ72qX8qnBtWk?filename=mainnet-chainlink-elf.json)

[And then how it renders on OpenSea.](https://opensea.io/assets/0x8d78277bc2c63f07efc2c0c8a8512de4ad459a05/1)

[More information on deploying and listing on opensea.](https://blog.chain.link/build-deploy-and-sell-your-own-dynamic-nft/)

Comment: _setTokenUri uses tokenId, not hash. Is there a recommended way to set the token URI using the hash?

Comment: What do you mean? TokenURI is based on the TokenID. What do you mean tokenhash?

Comment: The URI for IPFS ends with the hash. _setTokenURI uses token ID. How is the token ID mapped to the hash? Do we override _setTokenURI in our token's contract, and maintain a mapping there?

Comment: You don’t use the hash, you use the URI of the hash. For example: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmT3nSKpJrEUWgeqGNiQPNEWcP2cousZNfQ72qX8qnBtWk?filename=mainnet-chainlink-elf.json

Comment: Dont know if standard is bad or can we do it otherwise, but this will imply we need to set URI for each NFT, which will cost a lot and we would like to set it once and then just use token id for each, but your example doesn't offer that as files are stored with name on the ipfs

Comment: You don't need to store the files with a name on IPFS. But you could also just override each NFTs tokenURI function to point to the same function, so you could set it and forget it.

Comment: Do you know whether Opensea also supports ipfs:// type URLs?

Comment: They do support those

Comment: Might I ask you how did you implement such rich storefront presentation on opensea with all those social button-links at the top?

Comment: Oh, that's just something opensea offers on their UI. You don't do that in the solidity code

Answer (score 0):

as of my understanding (still haven't done it), the tokenURI has to return an URL that points yo uto the metadata, that metadata containing the actual IPFS url. Take this with a grain of salt

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - I had the same issue on openseas. Works with the URI of BOTH:

1. JSON ends in .JSON
2. IMAGE file ends in .PNG